# With Minitest+Guard+Spork, all test suites and support files are being reloaded on each run

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, guard, spork, minitest

I'm running into a problem where everything in my test setup, including Spork's prefork block, is being reloaded and invoked on each run. It is taking 5-8 seconds for a test to fire off after guard picks up a change even though this is a new project so there are minimal tests and I even have an SSD.

Before I realized everything was reloading, I profiled it using the technique described by Jo Liss [here](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/profiling-spork-for-faster-start-up-time/) and I've included those hanging requires but obviously that didn't help since it's all being reloaded anyway. However, that's when I noticed this:

> Loaded Suite
>   test,test/controllers,test/controllers/manage,test/factories,test/functional/manage,test/helpers,test/helpers/manage,test/integration,test/models,test/support

I'm not seeing why it would reload everything. This is my first attempt at setting up minitest+spork+guard (i should have just gone with rspec, sigh) so I'm hoping it's something stupid. I'm including everything in hopes that someone has run into it or can easily spot what I've missed. Thanks in advance!

My files include:

> **test_helper.rb**

```
require 'spork'
Spork.prefork do
  #MiniTest::Rails.override_testunit!
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  require 'guard'
  require 'guard/interactors/readline'
  require 'guard/ui'
  require 'guard/interactors/coolline'
  require 'guard/interactor'
  require 'guard/dsl'
  require 'guard/notifiers/rb_notifu'
  require 'guard/notifier'
  require 'guard/minitest/notifier'
  require 'guard/minitest/runners/default_runner'
  Dir[File.expand_path('test/support/*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
  require "mocha"
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :reload_routes!)
  Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)
end
```

> **Guardfile**

```
guard 'bundler' do
  watch('Gemfile')
  # Uncomment next line if Gemfile contain `gemspec' command
  # watch(/^.+\.gemspec/)
end
guard 'spork', :wait => 65, :test_unit => false, :minitest => true, :minitest_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :bundler => true do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb') { "test" }
end

guard 'minitest' do
  watch(%r|^test/test_helper\.rb|)         { "test" }
  watch(%r|^test/support/(.*)\.rb|)         { "test" }
  watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch(%r|^app/models/(.*)\.rb|)          {|m| ["test/models/#{m[1]}_test.rb", "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb"] }
  watch(%r|^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb|)     {|m| ["test/controllers/#{m[1]}_test.rb", "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb"] }
  watch(%r|^app/views/(.*)\.html|)         {|m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r|^app/objects/(.*)\.rb|)         {|m| "test/objects/#{m[1]}_object_test.rb" }
end

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/.+\.(erb|haml)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{(public/|app/assets).+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{(app/assets/.+\.css)\.scss}) { |m| m[1] }
  watch(%r{(app/assets/.+\.js)\.coffee}) { |m| m[1] }
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
end
```

> **support/minitest.rb**

```
#require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/spec"
require "minitest/pride"
require "minitest/rails/shoulda"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "capybara/rails"

class RequestSpec < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end

MiniTest::Spec.register_spec_type /integration$/i, RequestSpec
#MiniTest::Spec.register_spec_type /object$/, MiniTest::Spec

class MiniTest::Rails::Controller
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

> **support/turn.rb**

```
require 'turn'
require 'turn/autorun'
require 'turn/colorize'
require 'turn/reporter'
require 'turn/reporters/pretty_reporter'
Turn.config do |c|
  c.natural = true
  c.ansi = true
  c.format = :pretty
end
```

> **Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# core
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'thin'


# infrastructure
gem 'heroku'
gem 'foreman', :groups => [:development, :test]

# application monitoring
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'


# view engine
gem 'haml', '>= 3.1.7'
gem 'haml-rails', '>= 0.3.5'
gem 'redcarpet' # markdown


# data persistence
gem 'mongoid', '>= 3.0.5'
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-store'
gem 'redis-rails'


# email
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'mailcatcher', :group => [:development]


# authentication and authorization
gem 'devise', '>= 2.1.2'
gem 'omniauth', '>= 1.0'
#gem 'authority'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify', '>= 3.2.0'


# view helpers
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 2.1', :group => [:development]
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 2.0.2'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'


# file attachments
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'


# url helpers
gem 'mongoid_slug'


# console tools
gem 'ansi',             :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'rack-livereload',  :groups => [:development]
gem 'pry-rails',        :groups => [:development]
gem 'growl',            :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'turn',             :groups => [:test]
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'progress_bar',     :groups => [:test]


# supporting libraries
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'nokogiri',                  :group => :test
gem 'ruby_parser', '>= 2.3.1',   :group => :test
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1',    :group => :development


# assets
gem 'less-rails',                 :group => :assets
gem 'therubyracer', '>= 0.10.2',  :group => :assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3',       :group => :assets


# guard
gem 'guard',                     :group => :development
gem 'guard-livereload',          :group => :development
gem 'guard-spork',               :group => :development
gem 'guard-minitest',            :group => :development
gem 'guard-bundler',             :group => :development


# minitest
gem 'spork-minitest',           :group => :test
gem 'minitest-rails',           :group => :test
gem 'minitest-rails-shoulda',   :group => :test,  :git => 'git://github.com/rawongithub/minitest-rails-shoulda.git' 
gem 'capybara_minitest_spec',   :group => :test


# mocking
gem 'mocha', :group => :test


# http testing
gem 'vcr',      :group => :test
gem 'webmock',  :group => :test


# factories
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Comment: have you tried profiling without guard, or just plain `rake test`?

Comment: @prusswan No, mostly because I assumed the issue surrounded guard or spork. What's weird is rake doesn't seem to do anything: rake test --trace ** Invoke test (first_time, not_needed). I'm assuming that's a minitest/spork strangeness but I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: try `rake minitest` then. The problem is that there are too many gems in play, while guard should not be a factor it will make things easier if it was. There are also a lot of similar require lines for the same group of gems, I won't be surprised if that resulted in some duplication. Probably best to just work backwards from an earlier version (like just after minitest-rails was added)

Comment: @prusswan i agree; i should have backed away from minitest when i realized how many gems i was having to bring in to get it to work. I found the issue though, there was some funkiness between spork and minitest that this pull req fixed: https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/spork-minitest/pull/5

Comment: I don't mean to say there's anything wrong with minitest though, it is just harder to get a larger number of gems working together with no hiccups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Spork and Minitest were actually not working as expected. In order to fix this, the following changes had to be made:

Inside of the Guardfile, `:drb => true` had to be added to minitest:

```
guard 'minitest', :drb => true do
  #...
end
```

However that alone will break guard/minitest/spork because it tries to force feed it the `-r -e` options which are not currently supported. You'll run into the following error:

```
Running: test/models/business_test.rb
Running tests with args ["-r", "/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-minitest-0.5.0/lib/guard/minitest/runners/default_runner.rb", "-e", "::GUARD_NOTIFY=true", "test/test_helper.rb", "./test/models/business_test.rb"]...
Exception encountered: #<LoadError: cannot load such file -- -r>
backtrace:
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-minitest-0.0.3/lib/spork/test_framework/minitest.rb:13:in `block in run_tests'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-minitest-0.0.3/lib/spork/test_framework/minitest.rb:12:in `each'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-minitest-0.0.3/lib/spork/test_framework/minitest.rb:12:in `run_tests'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/Users/chance/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
Done.
```

Fortunately, there is a [pull request for spork-minitest that fixes it](https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/spork-minitest/pull/5).

Once the gem was pointed over to the repo, it took a nice cut out of the load times. It isn't anywhere near as fast as node.js and mocha, but it is at least faster than rspec.

Comment: nice feedback. I'm running into the same issue now but the only thing thats working for me is to set :drb => false.... What advantage does having drb give me?

Comment: k thanks.. im running spring now.. its like zeus and has similar benefits as spork

Comment: @sambehera I just started using spring because of your comment.  It works quite well.  Thanks!

Comment: @SeanHill actually im back on zeus. i didnt find spring quite ready yet.. I think it will take some time to mature. Maybe YMMV and you might get better results with rails 4 .. ive only tested rails 3.2 so far